# Proxy/tunnel Java and Chrome web traffic through SSH

Tags: http, ssh, proxy

I have a remote server through which I want to do most of my surfing. I have SSH/SFTP access to the server.

Now, the ideal solution would be to run a tunnel in the background that'd connect and stay connected, and a way of configuring chrome to make use of it. At the same time, it should allow me to use Java (my current SOCKS 5 solution doesn't), and Chrome should be set up in a fashion that if I want to use my own IP, it'd be fairly easy/simple to switch.

I've searched high and low for a decent solution, but I've had no luck so far.
I hope I've described it well enough, but if not, ask away! Fingers crossed that one of you have a golden solution for me :)

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here since it is not a security question but a functional question — you've determined that you want your traffic to go through that ssh tunnel, and you're now at the stage of configuring your system to use that tunnel. What operating system are you running? Depending on the answer, your question might be at home on [ubuntu.se] or [apple.se] or [unix.se] or [su]. What exactly is wrong with Socks (which would be what I'd suggest) — which program isn't working?

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling to find out where to post. But I figured, since the end goal is security, that's where I'd post it, but thanks for moving it :) I'm on windows 7, and I've been running MyEnTunnel as an ssh tunnel, which works alright except it times out if not used for a bit (a setting I can't seem to change), and with it I've used SwitchyProxy. It worked alright'ish, but I had 3 gripes with it. First of all, MyEnTunnel timing out is annoying.

Comment: Secondly, the chrome plugin switchyproxy couldn't just turn off the proxy for one tab or window, it had to be them all. This might be a chrome issue though, I'm not sure. Thirdly, and most importantly, I couldn't get java to work through the socks 5 proxy, and no matter what I added to the whitelist, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh, I just read the superuser description, it's for windows! The name lead me to believe it'd be a linux or some other kind of *nix site. Silly goose I am, sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

Right, I *think* I've found an acceptable solution.

Still using MyEnTunnel, but now paired with FoxyProxy, and it seems to be more responsive/run better.

Last point on my todo list is to make sure the SSH tunnel doesn't disconnect if inactive for a bit, but I'm working on that.